# does leaving a hotspot on when no one is connected use data?

Tags: wifi, tethering

I am concerned. I do not want the hotspot using data and wasting data without anyone connected. I was told to turn it off but i normally leave it on. I want to find out if it does or if it does not.

Answer (score 2):

if it does it will be a very minimal amount. But it will drain your battery(if its a wireless device) and others have a chance of connecting to it if you leave it on (even if its password protected they have a chance of hacking it)

Answer (score 1):

I was just checking the same thing out. I went to the AT&T store and then I went to AT&T online and chatted with them. The hotspot does use data just being turned on. You can get unlimited data plans for $90/month. That is the only way it would be worth having a hot spot and leaving it on 24/7, IMHO.